# ng intercom is not working with angular 17

Tags: angular, intercom, angular17

```
I am getting below error while converting angular 13 to angular 17.

Error: Unexpected value 'IntercomModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
  ng-intercom version: **8.0.2**
  angular version: **17.0.7**
```

import { IntercomModule } from 'ng-intercom';

```
 app.module.ts
  IntercomModule.forRoot({
      appId: environment.intercomAppId,
      updateOnRouterChange: true
    })
```